# In Hindemith's terms, how do I classify this melodic gesture?

Tags: theory, terminology, melody

I am attempting to analyze the `G` note in the melody pictured below using Paul Hindemith's terminology/framework set out in his *Book 2*.

From what I can gather, the melodic formulae Hindemith is considered with include the:

- Repeat tone;
- Passing tone;
- Suspension;
- Anticipation;
- Unprepared or free suspension;
- Neighbor tone approached by skip;
- Neighbor tone left by skip;
- Accented free tone; and
- Unaccented free tone.

As you can see, the `G` is a non-chord tone that is approached and left by skip. So, I believe that would make it some sort of free tone.  That being said, the `G`, on beat 2.5, is not in a weaker or stronger metric point than the note which follows it, the `C` on beat 3.5.  Because of this, I don't see how it could be classified as either an accented or unaccented free tone.

How would you classify this melodic operation?  I would like to stick to the terms and definition found in the book I am referencing, so please let me know if I can provide any further information from the text.

[image: three measure melodic segment with chord symbols]

Comment: I think that to answer this, the harmonization for the entire measure is required.

Comment: Please see the OP--the F major covers all beats in this measure.

Comment: Cool. Is there a measure before and/or after? Those also could influence the interpretation.

Comment: Please see OP for a more complete image.  Thanks

Comment: What piece is this excerpt from? Honestly, the chord names for the entire first measure and the second chord name of the second measure (the one for the note you're asking about) look completely unbelievable (at least to me).

Comment: I'm curious of the origin of the example too. Is it supposed to exemplify Hindemith's teaching?

Comment: is the dominant to subdominant movement scary to you?  its from my own composition--no relation to Hindemith whatsoever

Comment: Scary? are you joking? The question is about NCT classification, the concern is about the melody. I wanted to know if Hindemith gave it as an example to go with the list.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis yeah, i'm joking.  wasn't sure if you were use to seeing "retrogressions" in this context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

In my interpretation, the best fit for the `G` is **neighbor tone both approached and left by skip**. I would also say it's part of an **incomplete [double-neighbor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changing_tones)** gesture, along with the preceding `E`.

---

#### Here is my thinking for each of the options given

Preferred answers are in **bold**; "okay" answer is in *italic*

- Repeat tone

Obviously not, since the `G` only occurs once.

- Passing tone

Again, obviously not, since the `G` is approached and left by skips in opposite directions.

- Suspension

Again, no, since the `G` isn't held over from the previous harmony.

- Anticipation

No, since the `G` is not part of the following harmony.

- Unprepared or free suspension

Also no, for the same not-a-suspension reason given above. (However, it's interesting to consider that, since the harmony in the previous measure is G, perhaps this tone could be perceived as a suspension under the right circumstances. Not here, though.)

- **Neighbor tone approached by skip**

To my ear, the `G` clearly functions as an (incomplete) upper neighbor to the preceding `F`. This becomes more clear by omitting the `E` — the overall sound of the melody is not significantly changed.

- **Neighbor tone left by skip**

Obviously, since I consider the `G` a neighbor tone, it is left by skip, thus....

- *Accented free tone*

If I were grading an exam that gave this as the answer, I would accept it. The `G` is accented by virtue of being both a syncopation and by being longer that the `E`. I find the "free tone" interpretation less convincing than the "neighbor" interpretation, but not unreasonable.

- Unaccented free tone

I would consider the `G` accented because of the notes that come before, but even excluding that, it's clearly not *un*accented for the same reasons I consider it accented.

Answer (score 2):

> ...that being said, the G, on beat 2.5, is not in a weaker or stronger metric point than the note which follows it...

Why does it matter what the following note is? Does Hindemith define accent differently than the standard?

The `G` is off the beat. It's unaccented.

You might say two syncopated notes creates a kind of accent, shifting things to the off beat, but a least in terms of non-chord tone classification, accent is on the beat, unaccented is off the beat.

Comment: Hindemith is concerned with the relative strength of tones, be it the tonal or metric significance.  I suppose this dynamic most relevant in suspensions, anticipations, and the like

Comment: It appears that you and @aaron have different definitions for accented/unaccented notes?

Comment: @286642, the context of the accent is the difference. Syncopation is accenting a weak beat. But in non chord tone definitions, all I have ever seen, syncopation is _not_ included, it's a different context, and in that context accent is about on/off the beat.

Comment: Actually, Hindemith points out this changing context at the end of chapter IV, book I. Essentially when the rhythm is syncopated, the normal strong/weak beat accents are reversed.